# Incorporating additional terms in a harmonic/fourier regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I am selecting among a set of linear models that contain a harmonic regression model with up to four sine and cosine pairs.

For visualization purposes, here is an example of the harmonic model with one and two sine/cosine pair.

```
omega1<-1/24
beta1<-1
omega2<-2/24
beta2<-2
t<-0:23
f1<- beta1*cos(2*pi*omega1*t) + beta1*sin(2*pi*omega1*t)
f2<- beta2*cos(2*pi*omega2*t) + beta2*sin(2*pi*omega2*t)
plot(t, f1, type="l")
plot(t,f1+f2,type="l")
```

I am trying to model the diurnal variability of a biological response. There is another variable, X1, that I suspect influences the periodicity defined by the harmonic regression, but I am not sure how to integrate this additional variable.

Looking at the model below, my questions are as follows:

```
t<-0:23
C1<-cos(2*pi*omega1*t)
S1<-sin(2*pi*omega1*t)
C2<-cos(2*pi*omega2*t)
S2<-sin(2*pi*omega2*t)
lm(Y~ C1 + S1 + C2 + S2)
```

If I want to model an interaction effect or main effect, do I do it like so?

```
lm(Y~ (C1 + S1)*X1 + (C2 + S2)*X1)   
lm(Y~ (C1 + S1)+X1 + (C2 + S2)+X1)
```

My understanding is that the sine term affects the phase shift and the cosine term affects the amplitude; however, I have no a priori hypotheses as to how X1 affects this diurnal cycle.  Is it necessary (or even sensible) to try and parse apart which one of those two components are influenced by this additional variable?

```
i.e. lm(Y~ C1 + S1*X1 + C2 + S2*X1)
```

The data can be downloaded here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tkmmt29o2tsaeam/AAC0rfMzesBksPnpDMC41c_Da?dl=0

Comment: Would you please link to or post the data?

Comment: Hi @JamesPhillips, I've edited to include a subset of the data. Thanks so much in advance for your help.

Comment: Are all of the "Y" values zero?

Comment: @JamesPhillips, to satisfy the character limit, I had to truncate the data, but I inadvertently cut out the section that had values of 1. The Y values are binary. Please see the updated link with the entire dataset, in the edited text.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the data file. Attached is my 3D scatterplot of the data, which indicates to me there will be difficulty in modeling the data - please check the axes values and verify my work.

[image: scatterplot.png]

Comment: This is just a subset of the data. My question (described above) still stands. How do I incorporate another variable that I anticipate will influence the diurnal periodicity of the response?

Comment: I personally am unable to advise based on this subset of data and the model you provided, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question - likely remaining unanswered, but I have some experience with harmonic regressions.

What I have done to study the effect of covariate is to compare two models. In a harmonic regression / cosinor analysis, the features of the curve can usually fully define the fit of the curve, such as the amplitude, phase shift, and mean values.

If adjusting for a variable among a population, can collect individual regression fits and compare those features.

Work by Fernandez has been the most helpful for me.
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/15332450/